# How do I make an image in the center of a screen?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code.
How do I set a image in the center of all screens?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hub.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button1">
    <img border="0" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.png" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my current CSS code

```
body {
background-image: url("beach.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to center home.png or beach.jpg?

Comment: Do you want to center vertically, horizontally, or both?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/background-position/) property:

```
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the image is not dynamic then you can add something like this to your css:

```
#button1 {
    width: 10%;/*or whatever size*/
    height: 10%;
    margin: 40% auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use class from the img and use display block and margin auto this is how you do it

hub.css

```
body {
background-image: url("beach.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img.displayed {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto 
}
```

your html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hub</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hub.css">
</head>
<body>

<img class ="displayed" border="0" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to horizontally center the home img...

Steps:

1. Make the home img stretch to fit the width of the parent button div by making it's width **"100%"** instead of "100" px:

```html
<img border="0" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.png" width="100%" height="100">
```

2. Change the css of your button1 div to this:

```css
#button1 {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;  //this does all the magic
}
```

To see it in action go to: https://jsfiddle.net/1215pcey/